# My section heading and figure in two different pages

Tags: floats, rotating

I'm having my section and figure in two different pages. What should I do to get it in the same page. Thanks.
This is my code:

```
\FloatBarrier
%\label{sec:****}
%\title{\\bfseries{Appendix A}}
\subsection*{********}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
%\begin{subappendices}
\label{sec:RobustDubai}
%\FloatBarrier
\subsection{###############}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[H]
    \caption{###################}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{epsfilename}}
    \label{fig:########}
    \caption*{\footnotesize Note:#####################.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the environment `sidewaysfigure` "produces a single page-size float with contents rotated ±90 degrees."  So a `sidewaysfigure` will always be alone on its page.  If you don't want that, then use an ordinary `figure` and rotate it manually.